Java Monty Hall simulation with an outcome of 0.61
I'm trying Java code to simulate the famous Monty Hall problem.

Running the code with 100.000 iterations returns an average of 0.61 instead of 0.66. I cannot find what's wrong with my code.
public static double MontyHall(int numTests) {
        int passedTests = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < numTests; ++i) {
            List<Integer> puertas = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(0,0,0)); //0wrong door, 1right door, -1opened door
            SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
            int rightDoor = random.nextInt(3);
            puertas.set(rightDoor, 1);
            int choice = random.nextInt(3);
            if(rightDoor == choice) {
                int aux = random.nextInt(2);
                for(int k = 0; k < puertas.size(); ++k) {
                    if(k != rightDoor && aux == 0) {
                        puertas.set(k, -1);
                    }
                    else if(k != rightDoor) --aux;
                }
            } 
            else {
                for(int j = 0; j < puertas.size(); ++j) {
                    if(j != rightDoor && j != choice) puertas.set(j, -1); 
                }
            }   
            for(int l = 0; l < puertas.size(); ++l) {
                if(l != choice && puertas.get(l) != -1) choice = l;  
            }
            if(puertas.get(choice) == 1) ++ passedTests;
        }
        return (double) passedTests /numTests;
    }

I run it with numTests being 100.000 and the outcomes are:
0.61116
0.61065
0.61111

Any help would be appreciated,thank you in advance.


Using SecureRandom is overkill for Monte Carlo simulation. 2) Creating new instances of a random object for each iteration of your loop is expensive and unnecessary. 3. Why are you generating aux, a third random value? The Monte Hall problem involves a deterministic choice, to switch or not to switch. If your initial choice was correct and you switch, you lose. If your initial choice was wrong and you switch, you win because you started with a loser and Monty Hall has now shown you the only other loser. The probability of winning if you switch is 1 - probability your 1st guess was right



I read something like SecureRandom generates something closer to TrueRandom than the regular Random class so I thought it might be better for this but now I know it isn't. 3) I removed the aux random value and just opened (set to -1) the first door that wasn't the right/chosen one and now it works perfectly, but I don't understand why adding a random value to decide which one of the 2 doors open ,when they aren't the chosen neither the right one, can make a difference since they both should be equal (at least in my mind they are equal). Anyways thanks a lot for the answer and the advices!


Randomizing the door choice in a "switch" scenario makes no sense. Monty Hall will never show you the door you picked, nor show you the winner if it's a door you didn't pick. If you switch, there's only one choice to switch to, so making a randomized choice makes no sense. If you want to know the win/loss probability of switching, always make the switch and count how often you win. That also gives you win/loss for not switching, which is just the complementary probability.

As for SecureRandom vs Random, both behave the same way distributionaly. The next value from Random eventually becomes predictable, but the ensemble of values still behaves like uncorrelated uniform random variables when analyzed statistically. SecureRandom's sequence is statistically the same, but is unpredictable. The unpredictability comes with a greater computational cost-per-value. Worth it for crypto, not worth it for statistics.

FYI, you don't need to copy your Arrays.asList() to a new ArrayList. The former is mutable, just not resizable.

@pjs It's not randomizing the switch. It's randomizing which door opens when they're both empty.

@shmosel Thanks for clarifying. It's still unnecessary, because if they're both empty then you're switching away from the winning door. You've lost regardless of which door gets exposed. All of the power is in the switch/stay decision.

There are two bugs in your code, both a result of missing break statements in your loops.
The first is triggered when rightDoor and choice are 1, and aux is 0. The k loop opens both doors 0 and 2, which causes the l loop to never update choice, producing a false positive.
The second is the l loop itself. When choice is switched to a lower available door, the loop continues and finds l != choice once again true for the original value, and switches it back, inverting the experiment for those cases.
The j loop is harmless, because only one door will ever be neither rightDoor nor choice. But it's still a waste of cycles to continue iterating. Once you've found the index you're looking for, just break the loop.
If you haven't yet familiarized yourself with the debugger, this is a great opportunity to do so. Following the execution line by line would allow you to pinpoint exactly where the code strays from your intent.
